# Using Acrobat javascript to write a text file

Tags: javascript, text, adobe, acrobat

I am using acrobat XI to write some script. What I would like to do is 1) get the current processed pdf file name and 2) just simply output a text file

```
var textValue = "test";
var doc = this.createDataObject({cName: "test.txt", cValue: textValue});
this.exportDataObject({cName: "test.txt", nLaunch:0});
```

This is working , but I would like to provided a fixed path , I tried saveAs but it seems only for pdf , exportAsText not working as well.

Are there any way to fix it? thanks

Comment: Flashdevelop setup prompts you to install flex framework for you. Try using that instead. Or else set the framework's path in the properties.

Answer (score 1):

#### Official documentation says:

> Example: Save the current document in rich text format:

`this.saveAs("/c/myDocs/myDoc.rtf", "com.adobe.acrobat.rtf");`

I guess you can replace RTF format with TXT (`com.adobe.acrobat.plain-text`):

```
this.saveAs("test.txt", "com.adobe.acrobat.plain-text"); // try this
```